# Django url having %20 issues

Tags: django

One of my urls in url.py goes like this is like this

```
path('<str:subject>/<str:agglevel>/<str:cust_cd>/',views.Customer.as_view())
```

cust_cd takes value from UI. cust_cd is basically customer name which is a string value.
Url works fine for single words for cust_cd. Ex:Google,Gmail  etc. But when I give words with spaces like Ex:You tube I get 404 error. It says you%20tube not found. Am not able to figure out how to configure url so that it accepts space characters.

Answer (score 0):

in your urls.py file

instead of

```
<str:cust_cd>
```

try this

```
<slug:cust_cd>
```

for more information check out this link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters